# Programmatically remove images and videos from html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, hpricot

I'm working on Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and I've got a website in which users type posts. Each of them has a short description that is shown in the main page. That description is automatically built from the original, but it's just truncated so it reaches a max of 240 characters.

The problem is those descriptions may contain images or videos, and I don't want them to appear when I truncate those strings. I'm using `Hpricot` plugin to parse HTML, and the following regular expression to parse images:

```
body = Hpricot.parse(html_body)
body = body.to_s.gsub(/<img .*?>/, '')
```

This is removing images, but sometimes it leaves a string instead, for example it says "image" or "img" where the image was before. Now, for example, I see a loose "spam" text remaining after I deleted an image from the description. Maybe the regex is not correct.

Does anybody know which is the right regex for removing images, and also videos from html?

Comment: Why don't just avoid add some html in you content. After you can do some multi gsub to avoid what you want.

Comment: Avoid what? I do want users to insert images and videos, but those should be visible in the post's page, not in the short description on the home page.

Answer (score 2):

It seemn go me that you are searching for `img` with a *space* after it.

Don't you want this so that you can grab the `<img` and everything up to but not including the `>` and then grab the `>`?

Hard to say if it works without source input.

```
<img([^>])+
```

CAUTION: will NOT work with nested tags.